# How is JVM memory usage calculated?

Tags: memory, java, elasticsearch

I am tuning my Elasticsearch cluster, and see that the memory usage doesn't line up. Running "`free`" on my instance:

```
free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       30881324    17072320      238216       49736    13570788    13313528
Swap:             0           0           0
```

We see that there is `30GB` on the machine.

ES was tuned to use 50% of available memory (or max 30GB for oop reasons), and I can verify, here, the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` flags are set to `15078m`:

```
/bin/java -Xms15078m -Xmx15078m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -server -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch -Des.distribution.flavor=default -Des.distribution.type=rpm -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -p /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid --quiet
```

But when running "top" we see a different story.

`%MEM` is at `59%` , many times will show `85%` or more (triggering nagios alerts):

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
24366 elastic+  20   0   54.9g  17.5g   1.6g S 267.7 59.3   1849:57 java
```

Answer (score 1):

You have capped the heap size to 15 GB but the JVM is using more than that: stack and native memory, some of which is managed by the JVM (metaspace).

The `pmap -x <pid>` command might help identifying where the extra 2.5 GB is used, stack, heap.

The `ps -o nlwp <pid>` command will give you the number of threads. Each thread is consuming 1MB of memory in your case so one thousand threads will use 1 GB.

The `jstat -gc <pid>` command will show the size of the used metaspace under the MU column.

If the memory is used by the metaspace, you can limit its  using this option:

```
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g
```